# Fetch value from Database and fill all textbox if dropdown value change

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am trying to fill all textbox value depend on dropdown value selection. And I also fill dropdown value by SQL query. Here is HTML Code:

```
<select name="name" ID="name" class="form-control">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<?php
$qu="Select DISTINCT Cname from Client_table";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($res))
{ 
    echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0] </option>";
                                            
}
?> 
</select>
<label>Address</label><input type="text" name="add"/>
<label>Contact</label><input type="text" name="con"/>
```

DataBase:

```
  Client_table
   C_no             Cname           Caddress          Ccontact
    1               Mohit             xyz             0123645789
    2               Ramesh            abc             7485962110
```

Here I am confused that how to find address and contact of a client based on dropdown selection and fill textbox with this values

Comment: Do you have more clients with the same name in the table?

Comment: For example: If `Mohit` has two records in the table, then he has two different addresses, or two different contact numbers. One in each record. Then it would be wrong to make a `DISTINCT`, because then you would fetch only one address (or contact phone) into your combobox...

Comment: Not now but may be in future. Currently i have only 1 record in my table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname="stack";
// Create connection
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$qu = "SELECT DISTINCT Cname,Caddress,Ccontact FROM Client_table";
$res = $conn->query($qu);
?>
<select name="name" ID="name" onchange="myFunction()" class="form-control">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<?php

while($r = mysqli_fetch_row($res))
{ 
    echo "<option data-add='$r[1]'  data-con='$r[2]'  value='$r[0]'> $r[0] </option>";
}
?> 
</select>
<label>Address</label><input type="text" name="add" id="add"/>
<label>Contact</label><input type="text" name="con" id="con"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


    function myFunction(){
        var address = $('#name').find(':selected').data('add');
        var contact = $('#name').find(':selected').data('con');
        $('#add').val(address);
        $('#con').val(contact);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes It is working now. But will you please tell me it work for same name client or not.

Comment: yes it will work for same name client .if you face any problem you can inform me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change the query to

```
Select DISTINCT Cname,Caddress,Ccontact from Client_table
```

And change the following statement

```
echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0] </option>";
```

To

```
echo '<option data-add="'.$r[1].'" data-con="'.$r[2].'" value='.$r[0].'> '.$r[0].' </option>';
```

Modify select as

```
<select name="name" ID="name" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction()">
```

Add the following javascript

```
function myFunction(){
 var index = document.getElementById("name").selectedIndex;
    var add = document.getElementById("name").options[index].getAttribute("data-add");
var con = document.getElementById("con").options[index].getAttribute("data-con");
document.getElementsByName("add")[0].value = add;
document.getElementsByName("con")[0].value = con;
}
```

[JsFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/gireeshcse/ct7ybgkt/)

Comment: Did you add **onchange="myFunction()" to select and changed query and echo statement accordingly>Beacause i tried like that it worked.

Comment: yes i changed <select> it calling the function but not fill the value in textbox

Comment: Check this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfgnfukw/6/) and it is working

Answer (score 2):

**A bit of description**: The first time when you are accessing the page (`index.php`) the data is loaded into the combobox. Each `option` tag receives the client number as value (`C_no`) and other details, as text.

On the other hand, when you are selecting a value in the combobox, you need to fetch additional client data from the database. For this you need jquery and ajax. With it, when the value of the combobox changes, you must make an ajax request to the server (`getClient.php`). As response it sends you the corresponding data from the database table. You then take the data and put it wherever you like - in this case in the inputs.

**A bit of suggestion**: I would recommend you to start using prepared statements - in order to avoid sql injection - and to not mix php code for fetching data from db with html code. Just separate them. First, fetch data on top of the page and save it into an array. Then, inside the html code, use only the array to iterate through fetched data.

---

#### index.php

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$sql = 'SELECT C_no, Cname, Caddress FROM Client_table ORDER BY Cname ASC';

// Prepare the statement.
$statement = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);

// Execute the statement.
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

// Get the result set from the prepared statement.
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statement);

// Fetch the data and save it into an array for later use.
$clients = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Free the memory associated with the result.
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Close the prepared statement. It also deallocates the statement handle.
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#name').change(function (event) {
                    var cNo = $(this).val();

                    if (cNo === 'Select') {
                        $('#address').val('');
                        $('#contact').val('');
                    } else {
                        $.ajax({
                            method: 'post',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url: 'getClient.php',
                            data: {
                                'cNo': cNo
                            },
                            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                if (!response) {
                                    alert('No client data found.');
                                } else {
                                    $('#address').val(response.address);
                                    $('#contact').val(response.contact);
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
                            },
                            cmplete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                                //...
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding: 30px;
            }

            input, select {
                display: block;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <select name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
                <option value="Select">- Select -</option>
                <?php
                foreach ($clients as $client) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $client['C_no']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $client['Cname'] . ' (' . $client['Caddress'] . ')'; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?> 
            </select>

            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address"/>

            <label>Contact</label>
            <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact"/>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### getClient.php

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';

// Validate posted value.
if (!isset($_POST['cNo']) || empty($_POST['cNo'])) {
    echo json_encode(FALSE);
    exit();
}

$cNo = $_POST['cNo'];

$sql = 'SELECT 
            Caddress AS address,
            Ccontact AS contact
        FROM Client_table 
        WHERE C_no = ? 
        LIMIT 1';

// Prepare the statement.
$statement = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);

/*
 * Bind variables for the parameter markers (?) in the 
 * SQL statement that was passed to prepare(). The first 
 * argument of bind_param() is a string that contains one 
 * or more characters which specify the types for the 
 * corresponding bind variables.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
 */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'i', $cNo);

// Execute the statement.
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

// Get the result set from the prepared statement.
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statement);

// Fetch the data and save it into an array for later use.
$clientDetails = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Free the memory associated with the result.
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Close the prepared statement. It also deallocates the statement handle.
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

if (!isset($clientDetails) || !$clientDetails) {
    echo json_encode(FALSE);
} else {
    echo json_encode($clientDetails);
}

exit();
```

#### connection.php

```
<?php 

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'your-db');
define('USERNAME', 'your-user');
define('PASSWORD', 'your-pass');

// Display eventual errors.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); /* SET IT TO 0 ON A LIVE SERVER! */

// Enable internal report functions.
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// Create db connection.
$connection = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);
```

#### Create table syntax

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Client_table`;

CREATE TABLE `Client_table` (
  `C_no` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Cname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Caddress` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ccontact` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`C_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Client_table` (`C_no`, `Cname`, `Caddress`, `Ccontact`)
VALUES
    (1,'Mohit','xyz','0123645789'),
    (2,'Ramesh','abc','7485962110'),
    (5,'Tanja','def','1232347589'),
    (6,'Paul','pqr','0797565454'),
    (7,'Mohit','klm','0123645789');
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript File:

```
 function getdata(str) {

 if (str == "")

 {

     document.getElementById("no_of_sms").value = "";
     document.getElementById("no_of_days").value = "";
     document.getElementById("descr").value = "";
     document.getElementById("state-pkg").value = "";
     document.getElementById("price-pkg").value = "";

     return;

}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 

{ 

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

} 
else
{

    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
        var data = xmlhttp.responseText.split("#");
        var db_no_of_sms = decodeURIComponent(data[0]);
        var db_no_of_days = decodeURIComponent(data[1]);
        var db_f_state = decodeURIComponent(data[2]);
        var db_f_price = decodeURIComponent(data[3]);
        var db_f_desc = decodeURIComponent(data[4]);
        document.getElementById("no_of_sms").value=db_no_of_sms;
        document.getElementById("no_of_days").value = db_no_of_days;
        document.getElementById("descr").value = db_f_desc;
        document.getElementById("state-pkg").value = db_f_state;
        document.getElementById("price-pkg").value = db_f_price;
}


  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","functions/getdata.php?q="+str,true);

xmlhttp.send();

}
```

PHP File :

```
<?php
        $q = $_GET['q'];
         $host="localhost";
          $db_username="root";
          $db_password=""; 

          $con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$db_username", "$db_password"); 
           if (!$con)
             {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
              }
             mysqli_select_db($con,"business_details");
             $sql="SELECT * FROM packages where p_name = '$q'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
             $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
           $db_no_of_sms = $row['no_of_sms'];
          $db_no_of_days = $row['days'];
         $db_f_state = $row['state'];
          $db_f_price = $row['price'];
        $db_f_desc = $row['description'];
         echo 
     $db_no_of_sms."#".$db_no_of_days."#".$db_f_state."#".$db_f_price."#".$db_f_desc;

    ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",                      
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data[0]['qty']);

      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          $('#qty').val(data[0]['qty']);
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.